# lowest value for given number

Tags: java, java-8, logic

I recently gave a codility test. There was a this question which I couldn't solve. Now that I'm trying at home, I would like to get help. I don't remember the complete question language, but I do remember the output how would the program respond. Here we go.

"write a java program, for a given number N, need to find the lowest number for the given N. N could be a billion number too." 
{this may not be the exact one, Sorry about that}

For Example:

1. N=1 then o/p is 0.
2. N=123 then o/p is 100
3. N=1234 then o/p is 1000 and so on.

My Solution: --just a workaround, this isn't actual logic.

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int N) {
        int pointer=0;
        if (N == 1) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            String digitsCount = Integer.toString(N); 
            for(int i = 0; i < digitsCount.length(); i++) {
                pointer++;
            }
            StringBuffer subString = new StringBuffer();
            int count=0;
            while(count < pointer-1) {
                subString.append("0");
                count++;
            }
            subString = subString.insert(0, "1");
            return Integer.parseInt(subString.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the outputs are what they are? Why when N=1 it should output 0? Why when n=123 it should output 100?

Comment: Alright, I got the point. So it was something like this:

N=123 => total digits are 3. the lowest number which is possible having 3 digits is 100.

N=1 => total digits are only 1. the lowest number which is possible having 1 digit is 0.

Comment: I see. Can you show your attempt at the problem? You can [edit] the post.

Comment: I have tried the solution, but somehow, I'm not feeling good about it. I'm unable to find the logic thru java, therefore I have just written workaround code. But not that good. 

{ I will add to the question }

Comment: @Sweeper : added to the question.

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: So you mean “the lowest number **with the same number of digits**”? Then, why don’t you write this into your question? Do you think, we can read your mind?

Comment: Your solution is fine, but well, a) the first (`for`) loop is obsolete, as you are incrementing `pointer` exactly as many times as `digitsCount.length()`, so you why don’t you just use the value of `digitsCount.length()`, i.e. `pointer = digitsCount.length();`… b) use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer` c) the `while` loop should be a `for` loop, as it’s a canonical example of a counting loop. d) Add `"1"` right before the loop that adds the `"0"`s, then you don’t need an expensive `insert` (which would have to shift all other characters).

Comment: Yes, this helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You! Guys. All the suggestions were helpful. Infact, every suggestion has a learning. Here is the updated code. Please accept if you think its good enough.

```
private static long solution(long N) {
        if (N == 1) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            String digitsCount = Long.toString(N); 
            int pointer=digitsCount.length();
            StringBuilder subString = new StringBuilder();
            subString.append("1");
            for(int i=0; i<pointer-1; i++) {
                subString.append("0");
            }
            return Long.parseLong(subString.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems to work fine. The only thing it doesn't take into account is the fact that `N` can be a very large number. `int` only has a max value of about 2 billion.

Here is my solution:

```
public static long getLowestNumberWithSameNumberOfDigits(long input) {
    if (input < 10) { // special case
        return 0;
    }

    long trial = 10;
    while (input / trial >= 10) {
        trial *= 10;
    }
    return trial;
}
```

Comment: Under which circumstance would this `trial < Long.MAX_VALUE / 10` check be necessary? Isn’t a simple `while(input / trial >= 10) trial *= 10;` sufficient?

Comment: @Holger The `long` overflowing was my concern, but now I think more about it, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Using math library, should be good for about 16 digits.

```
long getLow(long in) {
    if (in <= 1) return 0; // see note below
    return (long)(Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(in))));
  }
```

The calculation is undefined for in < 1; we return 0. For in = 1 we return 0 per original code, though returning 1 would surely be more consistent: 2,3,...9 return 1, so why not 1 returns 1?